# Converting pdf to dxf using pstoedit - How to fix the double border issue?

Tags: python, pdf, svg, inkscape, dxf

I'm currently using `pstoedit` to convert pdf files to dxf files.
This is the `pstoedit` command I'm using:

```
pstoedit -f "dxf: -ctl -mm" input.pdf output.dxf
```

I get a file `output.dxf` from a file `input.pdf` but circles and squares in `output.dxf` have double borders instead of single borders.

The desired result is:

circles:

[image: circles]

squares:

[image: squares]

But current result is:

circles:

[image: circles]

squares:
[image: squares]

How can I fix this issue?

I've tried to convert a pdf file to a dxf file using the `inkscape` command.
I converted a pdf file to a svg file first and converted this to dxf file.

This is the `inkscape` command I've used:

```
inkscape input.svg --export-type=dxf --export-extension=org.ekips.output.dxf_outlines -o output.dxf
```

Here, instead of one perfect circle, I got a circle made up of 4 arcs.

circles
:
[image: circles]

So I moved to `pstoedit` and now I'm facing above issue.

Is there any proper way to convert a pdf file to a dxf file? I would like to modify the current commands to get the desired results(prefer to use `pstoedit` command).

Comment: Looks to me like pstoedit is using strokepath in some way. The result of strokepath is only suitable for filling, not stroking. From the PLRM "In general, it is not suitable for
stroke, as it may contain interior segments or disconnected subpaths produced by
strokepath’s conversion from stroke to outline" . That's what the interior segments of the 'circle' look like. That and the rather coarse path flattening. That should be fixable in pstoedit I'd have thought (don't use strokepath!) You're probably best to go back to the original document before it was a PDF though.

Comment: @KenS Is it possible to get flatten circles using pstoedit command CLI? Is there any additional option in this pstoedit command?

Comment: @KJ Is there any way to at least group each circle which is consisted of 4 arcs (actually all pieces are POLYLINE here) after this inkscape command?

Comment: I'm not familiar with pstoedit so it's not really possible for me to help. From what little I know it's a PostScript program, so it should be possible to avoid using strokepath, if that is the problem. Circles in PostScript need not be Bezier curves, the 'arc' operator draws a segment of a circle and can be used to draw an entire circles. In **PDF** however, there is no arc operator, so PDF circles are always a series of Bezier curves, there's no way to avoid that, and I don't know what you mean by 'group' the arcs, almost certinaly though the answer is 'no'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By adding this option(`-polyaslines`), the initial goal of eliminating the double border was achieved.

`pstoedit -f "dxf: -ctl -mm -polyaslines" input.pdf output.dxf`

For more information, visit this pstoedit manual site.
http://www.calvina.de/pstoedit/pstoedit.htm